# How to use an IF condition in a Scope that uses a SELECT function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to use the condition "if" in a scope that uses the "select" method?

i want to say:
if event.externalattendinglist.present? go ahead and display info on this code event.externalattendinglist.users.empty?

in the event.rb:

```
scope :events_with_externalattendinglist_nousers, -> { select {|event| event.externalattendinglist.users.empty? }}
```

how would i add an `if event.externalattendinglist.present?` to the above scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails 5, you can use below scope:

```
scope :events_with_externalattendinglist_nousers, -> { 
  left_outer_joins(:users).where(users: {id: nil}). # select event associate with no users
  joins(:externalattendinglist) # select event has at least one externalattendinglist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using this `select` in a `scope`. Scopes are supposed to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes. This use of [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) returns an array instead.

Comment: thank you soo much for the information. Will not use select in scopes. much appreciated